# Xamarin.Forms unhide keyboard on lost focus on Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I develop chat application on Xamarin.Forms. 
I need to don't hide keyboard when I press Send button and hide keyboard when I tap  anywhere else. 
I made it for iOS. 
Can I make the same for android?

Answer (score 1):

Found a very simple method to achieve this goal, you can simply place a `Button` on the top of an `Entry` like this:

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="End">
    <Entry x:Name="MessageEntry" TextChanged="MessageEntry_TextChanged_1" />
    <Button x:Name="SendButton" Text="Send" HorizontalOptions="End" Clicked="Button_Clicked" IsEnabled="False" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageEntry.Text = null;
}

private void MessageEntry_TextChanged_1(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageEntry.Text != null)
        SendButton.IsEnabled = true;
    else
        SendButton.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

Tested on Android 6.0 emulator, works fine to me, you can customize the `Button` to make it looks more beautiful in this view:

[image]

Comment: Using this way your text will be under the button. Even if you’ll set right padding to entry that will equal to width of button, this method won’t work every time. Are there other solutions of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can have in your PCL a scrollview element in which you add you entry element, when you tap on the entry element it will bring the keyboard and not hide it, it only hide it when tapped on a different portion of the screen. let me know if it help

Comment: I can't use scrollview together with listview. Listview scroll won't work